# Защита от XSS в автоматическом режиме для всего сайта

Tags: php, xss

Хочу внедрить автоматическую защиту от xss.

На ум приходит просто в главном файле в цикле перебрать все GET POST запросы и применить к ним htmlspecialchars, вместо того, чтобы вставлять htmlspecialchars перед каждым POST GET. Такой вариант защиты приемлем?

Почему мне будет больно при обработке паролей? Что разломает?

Comment: Вообще защита от XSS достигается при экранировании __вывода__, а не ввода.

Comment: Просто используйте любой нормальный шаблонизатор, который использует htmlspecialchars автоматически, и не страдайте фигнёй. Ваш вариант лишь разломает всё к чертям, и вам будет особенно больно при обработке паролей или когда приспичит всё-таки разрешить немного html-кода

Comment: В битриксе есть модуль проактивной защиты, так он регуляркой все REQUEST данные бьет: `<sc  ript` (через пробел) - не будьте как битрикс, используйте шаблонизатор.

Answer (score 0):

Для большинства ситуаций это подойдет:

```
htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Однако если в будущем вам понадобится разрешить ввод html могут возникнуть проблемы
Есть библиотеки, так называемые purifiers, например http://htmlpurifier.org/
Они будут за вас все делать

Answer (score -1):

Чтобы не было XSS надо корректно выводить данные. А принимать и хранить всегда надо как есть. Поэтому нет, предложенный тобой способ - ерунда, а от библиотек, которые предлагают что-то подобное надо держаться подальше.

Comment: Минусаторы, а вот обоснуйте своё мнение.